# Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo g400 cannot boot normally

Tags: intel-graphics, ivybridge, sandy-bridge

I have been trying to use Ubuntu 14.04; before that I was trying 13.10, but due to the hardware structure of my Lenovo g400 Intel® Core™ i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4 and VESA: Intel® Sandybridge/Ivybridge Graphics I can't get it to work.

I am able to boot only in recovery mode because a normal boot is stopped by few flashes, a black screen and then a "Low Graphics Mode" window from which I can go nowhere.